# istream operator

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    HandPhone A,B;
    A>>B;//overloading operator>> to simulate sending sms to another handphone(object)
    return 0;
}
```

How should I declare the istream operator to simulate sending sms to another handphone(object)?

Comment: @ukhti--formatting would make this question quite a bit easier to read and possibly answer. :-)

Comment: @ukhti--You're also asking a very broad question.  Please read the FAQ and try to narrow the focus of your question a bit.

Comment: Wouldn't a syntax like:   B << "Message" << A     be more readable? In the syntax that you've proposed you have no concept of a message. Though I should say, rather than overloading the operator right away, you should implement a public function, like: message( char* message, const HandPhone& from);

Answer (score 7):

This is how to define the >> operator:

```
void operator >> (HandPhone& a, HandPhone& b)
{
    // Add code here.
}
```

I have set the return type to void as I am not sure chaining would make sense.

But it is considered bad design (in the C++ world) to overload operators to do random tasks as it makes the code hard to read. The streaming operators >> and << have a very well defined meaning but sending a message does not look that much like streaming that I would would want to to use the operator this way. I would expect that unmarshalling the object at the destination end of the stream would produce an object very similar to what was placed in at the source end.

It is a lot easier to do something like this.

```
B.sendMessageTo(A,Message("PLOP"));
```

Answer (score 3):

[std::istream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/) is a class, not an operator.  The << and >> operators can be defined for any two types:

```
class A;
class B;

A operator << (A& a, const B& b)    // a << b;  sends b to a.
{
   a.sendMessage(b);
   return a;
}
```